# conditional iterator over two arrays with STL

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have two arrays. The typs are int and bool. 
The bool array indicates if an element is already deleted or not. 
Now I want a function that returns an iterator which only iterates over not deleted elements. Important is that the function should not allocate new memory (like for copying the element in a new vector). Is there a way to do this with standard STL?

```
    std::array<int,5>  element={ 1   , 2   , 4    , 8    , 10   };
    std::array<bool,5> deleted={ true, true, false, false, true };
    std::vector<int>::iterator getNotDeleted(){
             ...
    }
```

Example:

```
   deleted= { true, true, false, false, true };
   element= { 1   , 2   , 4    , 8    , 10   };
   getNotDeleted should return a std::vector<int>::iterator that Iterates over 
   {4,8}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `std::vector<int>` be easier than this whole mess? Erase what you want and it's not there when you iterate over everything.

Comment: Is there any reason why being `deleted` is not the same as being removed from the container?

Comment: "`bool` array"? "the type is `bool *`"? So what is it, an array of bools or an array of bool pointers? Ditto for `int *` and `vector<int>`.

Comment: The element array can be a std::vector<int>. Important is that the function should not allocate new memory.

Comment: okay I edited the post. It is an array of bool/int values.

Comment: @martins `std::array<int>` is wrong, that's not a real type

Comment: Are you deleting int from element array when you make a bool value true in deleted array ? If so, whatever elements left in element array, all are non deleted. whats the point of looping through only not deleted elements ?

Comment: @bjskishore123: quite obviously they aren't being removed from teh element array

Comment: yes they are not deleted. Just marked as deleted. This is important for the algorithm.

Comment: What will you do with the iterator?

Comment: Do you realize that iterators are like pointers?

Comment: @IanMedeiros I want to iterate over elements that are not marked as deleted.

Comment: You could certainly *create* an iterator to do this, but I don't think any supplied as standard does so. Alternative, you could consider using a `valarray`, which does support this kind of functionality directly.

Comment: You can do that by defining your version of operator++ for the iterators you provide. I don't know if it is possible in STL or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an iterator for this, simply construct an iterator that knows about both vectors, and it's current position in both vectors.  Then, when advancing the iterator, skip any elements that are flagged as deleted.

```
template<class T>
struct maybe_deleted_iterator {      
    typedef int difference_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    maybe_deleted_iterator();
    maybe_deleted_iterator(std::vector<T>& e, std::vector<bool>& d, bool is_beginning);
    maybe_deleted_iterator& operator++();
    reference operator*() const;
    pointer operator->() const;
    bool operator==(const maybe_deleted_iterator& rhs);
    bool operator!=(const maybe_deleted_iterator& rhs);
private:
    std::vector<T>* elements;
    std::vector<bool>* deleted;
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator e_iter;
    std::vector<bool>::iterator d_iter;
};
```

Then, simply iterate!

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int>   element = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    std::vector<bool>  deleted = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};
    maybe_deleted_iterator<int> it(element, deleted, true);
    maybe_deleted_iterator<int> end(element, deleted, false);
    for(; it!=end; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=40e4d1a54f71643ee9f885f82d71fb46-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba

LeSnip3R suggested having the members be begin/end pairs so that way it would work on any two containers, but I figured this was easier to understand for learning.  In real code I'd expect to see it done without mentioning a specific container like `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You could roll your own like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <class T>
struct no_op : std::unary_function <T,bool>
{
    bool operator() (const T& x) const
    {
        return x;
    }
};

template <class ItSource,
          class ItPredicate,
          class PredMod = no_op<bool> >
class ConditionalIterator
{
    ItSource _srcBegin;
    ItSource _srcEnd;

    ItPredicate _predBegin;
    ItPredicate _predEnd;

    void MoveNext()
    {
        while (_predBegin != _predEnd &&
               _srcBegin != _srcEnd &&
               PredMod()(!*_predBegin))
        {
            ++_predBegin;
            ++_srcBegin;
        }
    }
public:
    typedef ConditionalIterator & Reference;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<ItSource>::value_type ValueType;

    ConditionalIterator(ItSource srcBegin, ItSource srcEnd,
                        ItPredicate predBegin, ItPredicate predEnd)
                        : _srcBegin(srcBegin)
                        , _srcEnd(srcEnd)
                        , _predBegin(predBegin)
                        , _predEnd(predEnd)
    {
        MoveNext();
    }

    ConditionalIterator(ConditionalIterator const &other)
        : _srcBegin(other._srcBegin)
        , _srcEnd(other._srcEnd)
        , _predBegin(other._predBegin)
        , _predEnd(other._predEnd)
    {

    }

    ConditionalIterator &operator=(ConditionalIterator const &other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            _srcBegin = other._srcBegin;
            _srcEnd = other._srcEnd;
            _predBegin = other._predBegin;
            _predEnd = other._predEnd;
        }
        return (*this);
    }

    Reference operator++()
    {
        ++_predBegin;
        ++_srcBegin;
        MoveNext();
        return (*this);
    }

    ConditionalIterator operator++(int)
    {
        ConditionalIterator cit = *this;
        operator++();
        return (cit);
    }

    operator bool() const
    {
        return (_srcBegin != _srcEnd &&
                _predBegin != _predEnd);
    }

    ValueType operator*()
    {
        return (*_srcBegin);
    }
};

template <class PredMod, class ItSource, class ItPred> 
ConditionalIterator<ItSource, ItPred, PredMod> MakeConditionalIterator(ItSource srcBegin, ItSource srcEnd,
                                                              ItPred predBegin, ItPred predEnd)
{
    return (ConditionalIterator<ItSource, ItPred, PredMod>(srcBegin, srcEnd, predBegin, predEnd));
}
```

This code is far from complete, but it should get you started.
Then you use it like so:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<int,5>  element={ 1   , 2   , 4    , 8    , 10   };
    std::array<bool,5> deleted={ false, true, false, false, true };

    auto cit_valid = MakeConditionalIterator<std::logical_not<bool> >(element.begin(), element.end(),
                                                                      deleted.begin(), deleted.end());

    auto cit_delete = MakeConditionalIterator<no_op<bool> >(element.begin(), element.end(),
                                                            deleted.begin(), deleted.end());

    while (cit_delete)
    {
        std::cout << *cit_delete++ << std::endl;
    }

    while (cit_valid)
    {
        std::cout << *cit_valid++ << std::endl;
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: usually it's `make_conditional_iterator(element.begin(), element.end(), deleted.begin(), deleted.end());` since functions can deduce template parameters.

Comment: Also, `ItSource::value_type` is invalid for `std::array`, use `std::iterator_traits<ItSource>::value_type` instead.

Comment: Are you sure ? Both those sites show value_type as part of the type traits for std::array http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/
That's what I based myself on

Comment: Also your sample code uses post-increment which your class doesn't provide, and you only show the deleted elements.  When I fix both of those, your code still shows the first element regardless if it was deleted or not.

Comment: I'm quite sure, since GCC gave me a compiler error: `error: 'int*' is not a class, struct, or union type: typedef typename ItSource::value_type ValueType;`  (IE, `int*` doesn't have a `value_type` typedef)

Comment: [Here we go](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e5b36126f952ad131ad59aecfcaf4756-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: Also, since it's an input iterator, you're going to want some sort of `end` for it, since every algorithm will expect one.

Answer (score 0):

So, as Mooing Duck shows in the comment, you *can* define an iterator on arbitrary elements of an array.
I stand corrected, but I still suggest you think of less cumbersome solutions; you could either (and these are just the two solutions that popped my mind, there are so many more):

- sort the array keeping the valid entries in front, and iterate only from the first element to the n-th valid element
- use a container such as `std::vector` or `std::list` and actually erase the elements from your array, so you can iterate on them with a normal iterator (variant of this: copy the elements of your original array in an `std::vector` on which you can perform deletion, keeping your original vector safe)

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=40e4d1a54f71643ee9f885f82d71fb46-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba.  Also boost has [filter iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) that do similar things

Comment: I grant you, it _is_ quite ugly and cumbersome

Comment: Or http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c2f6156f9cc5f55b73182b3b43593905-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba for less ugly, but also minutely slower.

Comment: I can't add boost as dependency to the project